# repeating subpatterns in a regex

Tags: r

I have a few strings

```
c("Sioux City, IA-NE-SD",
"Fort Smith, AR-OK")
```

from which I want to extract the state names. As you can see, there are sometimes two states and sometimes three. I want to repeat the first subpattern to get the multiple states:

```
pat <- ".*(([A-Z]{2}-)+)([A-Z]{2})"
sub(pat, "\\2\\3", vec)
```

but this yields only the latter two states in my first case:

```
"NE-SD"
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.*` is greedy, and will eat as much as it can, including the first state if there are three. Try `.*?` instead.

Also, your replacement is `\\2\\3`. The second group is on the inside, before the `+` so it will only match one state and the `-`. You need to replace with `\\1\\3`

So in total:

```
pat <- ".*?(([A-Z]{2}-)+)([A-Z]{2})"
sub(pat, "\\1\\3", vec)
```